# Why can't Razor find my HTML Helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to port a "classic" ASP.NET MVC view to Razor and got stuck when trying to use a traditional (non-Razor) Html helper method. The helper method has the following signature:

```
public static string WrappedValidationSummary(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string SummaryError)
{
...
}
```

The helper method does work fine when using it in regular (non-Razor) views.

When using it in the Razor view like this:

```
@Html.WrappedValidationSummary("Mitarbeiter konnnte nicht angelegt werden.");
```

I get a run-time error message that

> 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'WrappedValidationSummary' and no
>   extension method
>   'WrappedValidationSummary' accepting a
>   first argument of type
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper'
>   could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

The Razor syntax checker in Visual Studio and Intellisense have no problem finding my extension method's definition. Recompiling the project does not help.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you added the helper's namespace to your Views/web.config?

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="CUSTOM_NAMESPACE" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

The above will only work if you're using an RC, if you're on an early Beta, you'll need to add the namespace in the page or Global.asax.

Also, I'd suggest changing the return type to `HtmlString`.

```
return new HtmlString(STRING_VALUE);
```

Comment: I had added the namespace to my web.config, but I wasn't aware of the extra config section for razor namespaces. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Is this still required for the RTM?  All the Razor bits seem to be included in the System.Web.Mvc assembly, but the Razor configuration classes don't seem to be there.  The docs for RazorWebSectionGroup says it's in System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll, but I can't find this assembly in the GAC.  Certainly you shouldn't have to reference a separate assembly for this.

Comment: @Derek Greer As far as I'm aware, it's all still applicable with RTM. My RTM projects look to include the same implementation.

Comment: So, do you have to include System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll?  If so, where is it. I couldn't find it in the GAC.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively you can use `using` in the first line of your view instead of **Views/Web.config** if you just want to use for specific view file.

```
@using your_current_web_namespace
.
.
.
@Html.WrappedValidationSummary("Mitarbeiter konnnte nicht angelegt werden.")
```

Comment: adding the namespace to my web.configs did nothing for the intellisense for me; adding the using statment worked.

Comment: Maybe the way how you add the namespace into Views/web.config got something wrong. or try to rebuild after adding the namespace.

Comment: If you add it to the Views/Web.config you need to restart Visual Studio to get it working (Rebuilding / Cleaning the solution doesn't  fix it).