# error following along with ASP.NET and MVC 5... error CS0246: The type or namespace could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I am following the examples in the book ASP.NET and MVC 5. Here is the view that results in the error:

```
@model SportsStore.WebUI.Models.ProductsListViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Products";
}

@foreach (var p in Model.Products)
{
    <div>
        <h3>@p.Name</h3>
        @p.Description
        <h4>@p.Price.ToString("c")</h4>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.PageLinks(Model.pagingInfo, x => Url.Action("List", new { page = x}))
</div>
```

Intellisense puts the red squigly line under PageLinks (however in the books project it correctly recognizes it). PageLinks is defined in the same project as follows (there are 3 projects in this solution):

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SportsStore.WebUI.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace SportsStore.WebUI.HtmlHelpers
{
   public static class PagingHelpers
   {
       public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html, PagingInfo pagingInfo, Func<int, string> pageUrl)
       {
           StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

           for (int i = 1; i <= pagingInfo.TotalPages; i++)
           {
               TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a");
               tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i));
               tag.InnerHtml = i.ToString();

               if (i == pagingInfo.CurrentPage)
               {
                   tag.AddCssClass("selected");
                   tag.AddCssClass("btn-primary");
               }
               tag.AddCssClass("btn btn-default");
               result.Append(tag.ToString());
           }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

For whatever reason it keeps telling me it cannot find the sportsstore namespace. I am so stuck here. I have actually compiled the completed project from the book and gone through to check and see if I can find any differences, no luck so far. I literally checked every reference and compared both web.config files (the main one and the one for the view). Even if I put a @using directive in the view it still doesn't find it. I've had a lot of problems compiling this project actually. Earlier I had a bunch of issues with ninject that required me to edit the web.config file.

If anyone would like a .zip of my entire solution I'd be happy to upload it somewhere (its about 24mb).

Any help appreciated!!

Thanks,
Tom

Edit:

Here is the appropriate section in the web.config file for the view:

```
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="SportsStore.WebUI" />
    <add namespace="SportStore.WebUI.HtmlHelpers"/>

  </namespaces>
```

Comment: Check your web.config and make sure the full namespace is there, see this answer for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4450122/546000

Comment: You've misspelled the SportsStore namespace in the last entry. You're missing an 's' before Store

Comment: I'll try to upload, it may have to be later. I'm at my state job and they firewall most of the regular upload sites. Could I possibly email it to one of you guys? I'll delete the bin and obj directories to keep the size down.

Comment: OMGGGGGGGGGG..... you are right Luke!! I can't believe I missed that... sigh it's always something stupid when I get really stuck like this

Comment: @user3298634 Happens to all of us.

Comment: Ok I just recompiled after fixing the typo, that was it. Thanks for the help guys I'm amazed at all the silly solutions I tried when it was just a typo

Answer (score 3):

You've misspelled the SportsStore namespace in the last entry. You're missing an 's' before Store.

Answer (score 1):

Try making the namespace available to your views through your web config.

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="SportsStore.WebUI.HtmlHelpers" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: I was pretty sure it had something to do with the web.config but mine is exactly the same as the books project, still no luck...

Comment: Can you tell me the path of the web config you are speaking of? It should be the one in the views folder.

Comment: I should also add that if I add a @using directive to the view intellisense properly picks up PageLinks (no red squiggly line) but it still fails with the same error

Comment: There are two web.configs, the one I was told to edit by the book is the one under my Views folder. There is one in the root of the application as well, should I try adding those namespaces to the root one?

Comment: I just added it to the root web.config file. I also had to add the stuff between <configSections></configSections>. Still the same error though

Comment: It should only be in the views web.config. I think we'll need to take a look at your solution.